# Remote Database - MySQL Connectivity Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting below warning while connecting to remote database through mysqli_connect.. It is working while connecting with SQLYog

```
 Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because 
 the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
 established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\connect\connect.php on line 9
```

Code ::

```
$hostname="xxx.xx.xx.xx"; 
$username="xxxx"; 
$password="xxxx"; 
$database="xxxx"; 
$port = 3306;

$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Connection failed'); 
}
```

Comment: Check that the remote database server allows incoming connections.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: ping your hostname form your server aand check it is reachable or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having troubles configuring PHP to work with mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272127/having-troubles-configuring-php-to-work-with-mysql)

Comment: @Saty : Ping is going to that server

Comment: And it is working when I'm connecting through SQLyog..May I know the reason behind this.